# A problem about projective variety

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

I have been reading the book *an Invitation to Algebraic Geometry*. And I meet a problem in section 3.2.

---

**Exercise 3.2.1** Show that every projective variety in $\mathbb{P}^n$ is compact in the induced Euclidean topology. Show that projective varieties are compactifications of affine varieties, in both the Zariski topology and, more significantly, in the Euclidean topology.

---

I am confused about that projective varieties are compact.

For example, $\mathbb{V}(x^2+y^2-z^2)$ in $\mathbb{P^n}$. Consider the points like $(1, \sqrt{t^2-1}, t)$. It's a curve in $\mathbb{A}^2$. How could it be compact in the induced Euclidean topology?

Comment: That's not a projective subvariety of $\Bbb P^n$. It's missing the points $[0:1:1]$ and $[0:1:-1]$ - with those added, it becomes compact. 

Hint for the question: it's enough to prove that $\Bbb P^n$ is compact, because a projective variety is closed in $\Bbb P^n$, and any closed subset of a compact space is again compact. Can you handle showing that $\Bbb P^n$ is compact?

Comment: @KReiser, I think I know how to prove now. Just a little confusing about compactifications.