# Projective varieties are compactifications of affine varieties

Tags: algebraic-geometry, zariski-topology, projective-varieties

This question has been asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3101709/proving-that-projective-varieties-are-compactifications-of-affine-varieties) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3313774/a-problem-about-projective-variety), though no answers have been given. It is exercise 3.2.1 in Smith's Invitation.

Showing $\mathbb{P}^n$ is compact boils down to showing it is the continuous image (under the projection map) of the (compact Euclidean) unit sphere in $\mathbb{C}^{n+1}\setminus \{0\}$, and then (as in a comment in the second post) projective varieties as a closed subspace of $\mathbb{P}^n$ (closed in Zariski topology, hence closed in Euclidean topology) is also compact.

I am struggling in showing that a projective variety is the compactification of an affine variety in the Euclidean (or Zariski) topology. Intuitively it makes sense - by adding on 'points at infinity' to some affine variety, it becomes compact - but I cannot seem to make it rigorous. I have the following ideas below.

If $X$ is an affine variety, the only associated projective variety $V$ I can think of is the one for which $X$ is the affine cone over $V$, where $V$ is constructed by identifying points in $X$ which lie on the same line. However, such a map $X \to V$ is clearly not injective, and so cannot be an extension (let alone compact). Should I be looking in a different direction here?

Comment: You can embed $\mathbb{A}^n$ into $\mathbb{P}^n$, for example, as the set of points where $x_{n+1}\neq0$. Then a subvariety of $\mathbb{A}^n$  goes in with it. Taking the closure in $\mathbb{P}^n$ (in either topology) gives you a compactification. The result is sometimes given the name of homogeneization of the affine variety. This is because if you start with an affine variety defined by polynomials $p(x_1,...,x_n)=0$, the embedding, in the chart $x_{n+1}\neq0$ of $\mathbb{P}^n$, is given as $p(x_1/x_{n+1},...,x_n/x_{n+1})=0$. Then the closure is given by ...

Comment: ... the polynomials $x_{n+1}^{d_p}p(x_1/x_{n+1},...,x_n/x_{n+1})=0$ for $d_p$ the degree of $p$. Note that $x_{n+1}^{d_p}p(x_1/x_{n+1},...,x_n/x_{n+1})$ is now a homogeneous polynomial, which motivates the name.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I suppose the wording of the question was confusing to me, but this makes it much easier to understand. Just to confirm, when we say $d_p$ the degree of $p$, we mean the degree with respect to the $x_i$?

Comment: @conditionalMethod also, I am not sure if this is the correct outline for the Euclidean topology. The Euclidean closure of an affine variety in $\mathbb{P}^n$ is not necessarily itself a projective variety is it?

Comment: Dear jcquell,  I have good news for you: the euclidean closure of an affine variety **IS** a projective variety, because that euclidean closure coincides (amazingly) with the Zariski closure. This sort of results goes under the name "GAGA", from the title of Serre's celebrated article [here](http://www.numdam.org/article/AIF_1956__6__1_0.pdf). The result I just mentioned follows from *Proposition 7* on page 12.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg thank you for the reference! It's interesting that Smith gives this as an exercise then, but I will gladly accept it.